# Cloud symbol next to apps

Tags: iphone, icloud

What does the cloud symbol next to an apps name mean? I’m assuming when you tap it it uploads data to iCloud but I’m not sure and I’m also wondering if there is a way to make these apps do whatever it is that they need to automatically. Below is an image of the symbol and what happens when I tap the apps. [image: Cloud symbol]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Source](https://www.theverge.com/2017/6/7/15752132/ios-11-storage-deleting-apps-messages-photos):

These are offloaded apps, new for iOS 11.  A cloud next to an icon means you enabled offloaded apps and this app was deleted, but the data was saved and you can re-download the app by tapping on it.  When you tap the app, it begins to redownload to your device, as you've seen.

To change this behaviour, go to `Settings -> iTunes & App Store` and change the switch for `Offload unused apps`.

Comment: When apps are offloaded does that take up less storage? Or does it take the same amount?

Comment: Apple says they take-up less storage space on your device when they're offloaded.  Once you download them, they use space on your device.  You can offload by use (default) or by specific application(s).

Comment: Note that if an offloaded app gets removed from the App Store you are out of luck.  If the app is on the device you can keep using it as long as an OS update doesn’t break it, but as soon as something is pulled from the AppStore, an offloaded app is broken.